# Executing cells in IPython equivalent to executing a Python script via terminal

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to convert an IPython/Jupyter notebook into a Python executable script and I've got it working for the most part but I have some instances where I would have, for example,

```
a = [1,2,3]
a
```

or

```
s = 'some string'
type(s)
```

Now, left as is in a Python script will not print the variable "a" and will not display the output of "type(s)" if I run

```
python myscript.py
```

in the terminal (in most cases). I tried using the built-in print function but sometimes it'll only display

```
<built-in .... >
```

which is not what I want.

I'm not sure if what I am asking is possible but I would like it to run the Python code above in the terminal as it would when I run it in a cell in IPython or Jupyter notebook. The reason for writing this conversion script is because it was assigned as a homework exercise to be completed and I would appreciate any hints on doing this. Just to be clear, I don't think this is a required for the assignment as the instructor never mentioned it in class, but I am just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the script print out, you'll need to explicitly use the `print` function. Eg,

```
a = [1,2,3]
print(a)
s = 'some string'
print(type(s))
```